# Ocultar URL SonataBundle / Symfony

Tags: php, url, symfony

El problema es que tengo una página la cual siempre muestra `"lapagina/web/app_dev.php/ES/"` en el Navegador, independientemente de la plantilla que estes visualizando, cuando le añado el "admin" `lapagina/web/app_dev.php/ES/admin`, carga el dasboard del SonataBundle y la URL queda así `"lapagina/web/app_dev.php/ES/admin/dashboard/"`, hasta aquí todo bien, el problema es que cuando me empiezo a mover por el Sonata, la URL empieza a mostrar siempre en la uta que me encuentro y quisiera que siempre se muestre esta`"lapagina/web/app_dev.php/ES/admin/dashboard/"`ruta a pesar de cambiar de plantillas del Sonata.

Comment: No estoy muy seguro si eso es posible, de hecho el propio sonata esta preparado para que el dashboard vaya indicando que admin esta ejecutando en ese momento. El routing va añadiendo cada ruta en la que navegas, para ir creando el breadcrumb y otras opciones, como las traducciones de ruta (por ej). Quizas podrias cambiar las traducciones y que te salga siempre /admin/dashboard...

Comment: Buscando he llegado a la conclusión de que tal y como yo lo quería "no se puede", se suele hacer mediante el servidor, ya sea en Apache con "mod_rewrite" o en IIS con "URL Rewrite" y es la solución que he escogido, gracias de todas formas!!

Comment: pensaba que querias poner siempre /admin/dashboard, no lo de quitar el app_dev.php. Efectivamente eso se puede hacer con el mod_rewrite, en el propio .htaccess que tienen los proyectos symfony. Lo siento, no te habia entendido.

Comment: No te preocupes, me he releído y podría haberlo expresado mejor la verdad. De todas formas, gracias por tu tiempo!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buscando he llegado a la conclusión de que tal y como yo lo quería "no se puede", se suele hacer mediante el servidor, ya sea en Apache con "mod_rewrite" o en IIS con "URL Rewrite" y es la solución que he escogido.